# Generate 100 random numbers and show all of them in a panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, numbers

I need your help.
I have problems with an application in HTML+Javascript. I need to generate 100 random numbers and show all of them in a panel. Also: when I will select ONLY 2 of numbers the sum of numbers must show up in other panel.
I did the html file and I tried to figure out how it's working, but still I need your help.
This is the HTML file:

```
<div id = "section1">
    <span class = "boxes" id="demo1" onclick = "sum();"></span>
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo2"></span>
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo3"></span>
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo4"></span>
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo5"></span> <br/><br/>     
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo6"></span>
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo7"></span>
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo8"></span>
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo9"></span>
        <span class = "boxes" id="demo10"></span> <br/> 
    </div>
   <div id = "section2">
        <span id="sum1" class = "sum"></span>
        <span id="sum2"></span>

    </div>
```

And this is the javascript

```
function myFunction() {
 var a1 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a2 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a3 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a4 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a5 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a6 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a7 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a8 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a9 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
 var a10 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = a1;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = a2;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = a3;
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = a4;
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = a5;
document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = a6;
document.getElementById("demo7").innerHTML = a7;
document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML = a8;
document.getElementById("demo9").innerHTML = a9;
document.getElementById("demo10").innerHTML = a10;
}

function suma(){
  var fn, ln; 
  fn = document.getElementById("demo1").value; 
  ln = document.getElementById("demo2").value; 
  result = (parseFloat(fn)+parseFloat(ln)); 
  document.getElementById("suma1").innerHTML = result; 
}
```

Can you help me guys with any sugestion?
Thanks

Comment: Read up on arrays and loops.

Comment: seriously, you need to at least spend couple days to read about how to code before you jump into it. It is NOT easy.

Comment: Any example Eric, please?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a typo bc in line 2, you call the function `sum()` but the function line 25 is `suma()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple: your code is trying to place the sum in an element with an ID of `suma1`.  However, you don't have an input with that ID.  Maybe you meant to use `sum1` or `sum2`.

Yes, coding is hard, and it's even harder to do it well.  Don't get discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
function add(a, b){
  var total = parseInt(document.getElementById(a).innerHTML);
  total += parseInt(document.getElementById(b).innerHTML);
  document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML =a + " + " + b + " = " + total;
}
for (var I = 0; I < 100; I++) {
  var i = document.createElement("span");
  i.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + "\n";
  i.id = I;
  document.getElementById("section1").appendChild(i);
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
</div>
<div id="section2">
  <span id="sum1" style="color:red;"></span>
</div>
<p onclick="add(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1))">click me to add two random numbers from above (also chosen randomly)</p>
```

Comment: Are you really using `I` and `i` as your main loop variables?  Bad practice if you ask me.

Comment: This code doesn't work. Doesn't show up any number, I don't know why.

Comment: @Dazzy The idea was not to spoon-feed you, if you read the source code you will find some techniques (for loops, createElement, innerHTML, appendChild) that should help you do what you want yourself. BTW what number doesn't show up? works perfectly for me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the correct onclick handler `suma();` and use `document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML` instead of value to get the text inside your span tags.

Edit: Added a solution

```js
function sum() {
  //Get list of html nodes and convert to regular array type
  var nodeList = document.getElementById("section1").childNodes;

  //Pick out two random elements
  var sum = getRandomNumber(nodeList) + getRandomNumber(nodeList);
  document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = sum;
}

function getRandomNumber(nodeList) {

  //Copy nodelist to local array so we can alter it safely with splice
  var array = toArray(nodeList);

  for (var i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);

    //Remove one element from the array and check if it's a valid number
    var element = array.splice(index, 1)[0];
    var value = parseInt(element.innerHTML, 10);

    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

//Copy array-like object to array
function toArray(list) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    array[i] = list[i];
  }
  return array;
}

//Generate numbers
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  var element = document.createElement("span");
  var container = document.getElementById("section1");

  element.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  element.onclick = sum;

  //10 spans per row
  if (i % 10 == 0) {
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }

  container.appendChild(element);
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2">
  <span id="sum1" class="sum"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, here it was just a typo. In my code is correct.
I did what you said, but still not working.